# Concatenate string in a particular format in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hana

I have a table which contains 3 columns

```
A.          B.           C.   
Abc.      Abc.           1
Abc.      Abc.           2 
Abc.      Abc.           3
Bcd.      Bcd.           4
Cde.      Cde.           2
Cde.      Cde.           4
Cde.      Cde.           4
```

I want to make them as a single row as following

```
A.           B.            C.   
Abc.       Abc.          1/2/3/-
Bcd.       Bcd.          -/-/-/4
Cde.       Cde.         -/2/-/4
```

Can anyone please help me out? Maximum number is 4 for C column. So the best case is 1/2/3/4.And if any repetition is there in C within same group of A and B column then it should be considered as one as in case of last two rows

Comment: Its clear that i want to group the rows to get a particular format output for C. Column

Comment: Completely unclear what you want to do and how.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky.  Here is one method:

```
select a, b,
       concat_ws('/',
                 (case when sum(c = 1) > 0 then 1 else '-' end),
                 (case when sum(c = 2) > 0 then 1 else '-' end),
                 (case when sum(c = 3) > 0 then 1 else '-' end),
                 (case when sum(c = 4) > 0 then 1 else '-' end)
                ) as cs
from t
group by a, b
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use tally table and `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT s.A, s.B,GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(m.C, '-') ORDER BY s.n SEPARATOR '/') AS C
FROM mytable m
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT A,B, sub.n
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A,B FROM mytable) t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 n  UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL 
              SELECT 3   UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL
              SELECT 6   UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL
              SELECT 9   UNION ALL SELECT 10) AS sub) s
  ON m.A = s.A
  AND m.B = s.B
  AND m.C = s.n
WHERE s.n <= (SELECT MAX(C) FROM mytable)
GROUP BY s.A, s.B;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/417900/28/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
   A       B         C     
 ------- ------- --------- 
  Abc.    Abc.    1/2/3/-  
  Bcd.    Bcd.    -/-/-/4  
  Cde.    Cde.    -/2/-/4
```

If you have more values, just increase the tally table range.

Comment: Sorry but i m using SAP hana environment and concat_group is not available in that

Comment: I mean group_concat